# I want to access rundeck through Java and get the list of jobs that were failed and restart them

Tags: java, rundeck

I am trying to access all the jobs of a project from rundeck in order to find the failed jobs and restart them. Also I want to check if all the nodes are up or not using Java.

When I try to create an instance for the `RundeckClient` using the `org.rundeck.api.RundeckClient` I am getting following error:

> 'RundeckClient(java.lang.String)' is not public in 'org.rundeck.api.RundeckClient'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: I don't know what client is "RundeckClient" but you can do it using rd-api-client as client: https://bintray.com/beta/#/rundeck/rundeck-maven/rd-api-client?tab=overview please give a look to this too: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rundeck-discuss/cPmxg39_pYM

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck has a rest API you can read about it from https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/#index-links

Create a restful web-service client and invoke the web-service end points.

Refer the Jobs section on the API documentation and use the appropriate api according to your need. You will need to generate token from the Rundeck and use it in your API calls.